# Google Apps Script: How to run split function on 2D array and keep column numbers the same

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, split

I'm running the split function on an array column in Google Apps Script, which in turn creates multiple columns. The number of columns varies depending on how many times the delimiter is triggered, which varies. So some rows will end up with 6 columns and others with 4, for example.

I'd like the output array to have an even number of columns, so those rows with less columns should be extended with nothing in the extra columns.

How do I set this into the equation? The current equation I'm using is as follows.

```
var splitarray = originalarray.map(function (row){ return row[0].split(" ") });
```

Logging this variable might get me something like this:

```
[[1,2,3],
 [1,2,3,4]]
```

And instead I want the output to be (in this example):

```
[[1,2,3,],
 [1,2,3,4]]
```

So that all arrays have the same number of columns.

*P.S. I know this can be done in the spreadsheet itself but this is part of a larger operation I'm doing in the script.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Calculate the maximum size of the row in map
- Fix the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of each row using calculated maximum size

```js
const originalarray = [["1,2,3"],["1,2,3,4"]];
let maxSplit = 0;
const splitarray = originalarray.map(function (row){ 
    const s =  row[0].split(",");
    maxSplit = Math.max(maxSplit, s.length);
    return s;
});
splitarray.forEach(row=>row.length=maxSplit);
console.info(splitarray)
```

- In `setValues(array2D)`, [`undefined` will be parsed as `null`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#adjust_handling_of_undefined_paramaters) and therefore the cell will be empty

Comment: Thanks a lot.If originalarray was already a pre-defined array (not the one I gave in the example), could we drop the first const?